# What plugin would make this happen? If is the theme

Tags: plugins, categories, themes, pages

Update:  My Responsive Version 1.9.3.6 has a bunch of custom post and page templates. When I update it to Responsive Version 4.3.6. I lose all the templates. Any ideas on how to keep the templates when I update?

---

I recently took over a web page for a company. The site has not been updated for years. How it works before updating:Information in put in post. When a new page is created the person picks page categories. Those categories tell the page what information to show. I contacted the cyber chimp and they say it's not a theme feature so I hoped someone could tell me what plugin would make this happen because I can't find a page categories plugin in the plugin list.

Before updating using theme Responsive Version 1.9.3.6. This is the page.
[image]

This is what the front end looks like

[image]

After I update to PHP 7, current wordpress version and Responsive Version 4.3.6. This is the back end view because there no content on the front end so I didn't see any reason to show it.
[image]

Thank you very much for any help
Kimberly

Comment: Well, it seems like a custom code in the backend of the theme only. Maybe a page template or single post with a specific category. Information is not enough to give a solution.

Comment: Thank you, I never stop to think about page template. On the old version there is a custom page template which didn't move when I cloned the website to a testing area.  Now I need to find that and figure out how to move it from one site to the other. See if that works. Thanks again

Comment: It sounds very much like the theme was customized, so when you update the custom work is getting wiped. Best practice is to create a child theme of the base theme, then update the parent theme. Here's some info on how they work - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: I made a child theme and have been ftp the custom pages into the child theme. The issue is that Responsive theme removed the custom page feature from the theme in version 4, according to Responsive theme support. Updating to the current Responsive theme is not a possibility. Either I never update the theme or I find a way to move the custom php pages into a new theme. I'm researching if that is possible. I've never had an issue like this before. I also have to figure how to get the where the page categories setting are stored and did the move the new site when I cloned the page. Thanks